# Inertia.js Vue JS Printing prop value as style

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I have the following inertia link component

```
<inertia-link v-for="project in $page.props.user.favorite_projects" :key="project.id" class="flex items-center px-6 py-2 mb-1 text-sm leading-6 text-gray-300 transition duration-150 ease-in-out group focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700" :href="route('projects.show',project.slug)">
     <div class="w-3 h-3 mr-3 overflow-hidden rounded-full">
        <div class="w-full h-full" style="background-color = {{ project.color }};">
        </div>
     </div>
     {{ project.project_name }}
</inertia-link>
```

Where project.color contains a hex color value like #fc8181, which is used to color the element based on the project.

However, the circle with this color value is not being shown in the dom.
Is there a way to display the project color as background color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to bind the style, try [style](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/class-and-style.html#object-syntax-2)

```
:style="{ background-color: project.color }"
```